# How to make sure that the person passed reCAPTCHA validation

Tags: php, captcha, recaptcha, contacts, contact-form

I have an contact PHP contact file,
i added the reCAPTCHA in my HTML theme under Contact forms
but i want the code to make  sure that the client or the person who want to contact passed the reCAPTCHA .. !

here's my PHP contact code:

```
<?
$name = $_POST[name];
$email = $_POST[email];
$type = $_POST[type];
$message = $_POST[message];

if ($name == "") {
die('name null');
}
if ($type == "" || $email == "" || $message == "") {
die("not null");
}

$myemail = "myemail@myemail.com";
$s = "$name";
$body = "<b>Message from Client</b> <br><br> Name: <b>$name</b><br> Package: <b>$type</b><br> E-mail: <b>$email</b><br> Message: <b>$message</b>";

$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'."\r\n";

mail($myemail, $s, $body, $headers);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('response' => 'success'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if statement, check if the captcha entered is the same as the defined. Perhaps pasting the form mark up? to see which captcha you are using?

Comment: can you make this for me im not pro PHP .. programmer !

Comment: Paste here the mark up of the form. so I can have a look.

Comment: @AmeerAssadi check this to validate your recaptcha using google in php.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php#client-side-how-to-make-the-captcha-image-show-up

Comment: as i saied i didnt use recaptcha.php
i just use one php file its cotact-form.php

Answer (score 0):

Trying using this snippet from [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php#client-side-how-to-make-the-captcha-image-show-up):

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "your_private_key";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
     "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
?>
```

Comment: but i didnt use recaptchalib.php file i just have html for contact forms + PHP file to send the forms